# Why is $\pm \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y/k)\delta (y)\frac{dy}{k} = \pm \frac{1}{k} f(0) $?

Tags: calculus, distribution-theory

From Griffiths, *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, pg. 48:

[image]

In the image above, the author makes the statement in the title of this question. But shouldn't it be

$$\pm \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y/k)\delta (y)\frac{dy}{k} = \pm \frac{1}{k^2} f(0) \text{ ?}$$

Why can't you say that $f(y/k) = \frac{1}{k} f(y)$

Comment: It is not Kronecker symbol. It is Dirac delta function.

Comment: What is the source for the quote?

Comment: What would make you think that $f\left( \dfrac y k\right) = \dfrac 1 k f(y)$? That is very remote from the truth. For example $x\mapsto\sin \dfrac x k$ oscillates between $1$ and $-1$, whereas $x \mapsto \dfrac 1 k \sin x$ oscillates between $1/k$ and $-1/k$, and the frequencies of oscillation of these two functions are different. $\qquad$

Comment: @CarlMummert, this comes from Griffiths's *Introduction to Electrodynamics*.

Comment: @CarlMummert Griffiths, *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, 4th edition.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I was thinking that if $f(x/k)=\frac{x^2+2}{k}=\frac{1}{k}x^2+2=\frac{1}{k}f(x)$. This was probably pretty appalling to a lot of people on here, and for that I apologize.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: thanks. Like any other direct quote, the source (and, ideally, the page number) should be given along with an image of a book, so that others in the future can look it up, and so that everyone has context of where the quote comes from.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat  Can you read the comments please ? $\delta$ is NOT the Kronecker symbol at all, but the Dirac delta distribution.

Comment: @user1952009 noted, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As *MichaelHardy* notes, it is not true that $f(y/k) = f(y)/k$, in general.

Let $h(x) = x/k$ and notice that $h(0) = 0$. Then, when we change variables $kx = y$, we have that $k\,dx = dy$. Hence, when we make the substitution in the integral, we have the composition $f\circ h$ in the numerator:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(kx)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(y/k)}{k}\delta(y)\,dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(f\circ h)(y)}{k}\delta(y)\,dy=  \frac{1}{\vert k\vert}(f\circ h)(0) = \frac{1}{\vert k\vert}f(0)
$$
since $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)\delta(t)\,dt = g(0)$, by property of the delta function. We have $\pm 1/k$ as a result of following through with our change of variables and noticing the cases where $k \lt 0$ and $k \gt 0$. I think you should see that we don't get $\pm 1/k^2$.

Comment: What does the open circle symbol mean?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat, the notation $(f\circ h)(x) = f(h(x))$ is the symbol used to denote function composition.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Indeed, there are too many unnecessary steps. It's sufficient with
>   $\ds{\delta\pars{kx} =
> {\delta\pars{x} \over \verts{\dd\pars{k\xi}/\dd\xi}_{\xi = 0}} = {\delta\pars{x} \over \verts{k}}}$

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{x}\delta\pars{kx}\,\dd x & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{x}\,{\delta\pars{x} \over \verts{k}}\,\dd x
= {1 \over \verts{k}}\,\mrm{f}\pars{0}
\end{align}

Comment: In your first section, aren't you dividing by zero?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat No. I'm using
$$
\delta\left(\,\mathrm{g}\left(\,\xi\right)\,\right) =
\sum_{k}{\delta\left(\,\xi - \xi_{k}\,\right) \over
\left\vert\,\mathrm{g}'\left(\,\xi_{k}\right)\,\right\vert}\quad\mbox{where}\quad
\mathrm{g}\left(\,\xi_{k}\,\right) = 0
$$
The above calculation start with
$$
{\mathrm{d}\left(\,k\xi\,\right) \over \mathrm{d}\xi} = k \not= \color{#f00}{0}
$$